# I need help to fix error when call traker.update with GOTURN tracking

Tags: python, opencv, tracking

I am learning using GOTURN openCV api to track objects. I am following guide from learnopenCV. After initialize tracker and come into the loop, I got the error when update tracker

```
ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-64-e7c5a34c2f7a>", line 1, in <module>
    ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\layers\convolution_layer.cpp:282: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Number of input channels should be multiple of 3 but got 1 in function 'cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes'
```

I am not sure what channel means. I got the frame from video file and the shape is (row, width, 3). I thought channel is 3 but it does not work. I did try with convert frame to gray scale with shape (row, width), but it still not work either.

Below is my code:

```
import cv2
import sys

background_path = 'images/images_G1_323/background.png'
background_img = cv2.imread(background_path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
#cv2.imshow('background image',background_img)

tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()

video_path = 'videos/G1_323.avi'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

#fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
if cap.isOpened() == False:
    print('ERROR FILE NOT FOUND OR WRONG CODEC USED!')
    sys.exit()

# Read first frame
ok, frame = cap.read()
ok, frame = cap.read()
ok, frame = cap.read()
frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
if not ok:
    print('Cannot read video file')
    sys.exit()

#motion = fgbg.apply(frame)
motion = cv2.absdiff(background_img,frame_gray)

_, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(motion, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(thresh1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh1, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
erosion_size = 10
dilate_size = 14
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (erosion_size, erosion_size)))
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (dilate_size, dilate_size)))

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
c = contours[0]
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
bbox = (x, y, w, h)

# Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
ok = tracker.init(frame,bbox)

while (cap.isOpened):
#
    #if ret is true than no error with cap.isOpened
    ok, frame = cap.read()
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    if ok==True:

        # Start timer
        timer = cv2.getTickCount()

        # Update tracker
        ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

        # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
        fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);

        # Draw bounding box
        if ok:
            # Tracking success
            p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
            cv2.rectangle(frame_gray, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
        else :
            # Tracking failure
            cv2.putText(frame_gray, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)

        # Display tracker type on frame
        cv2.putText(frame_gray, "GOTURN Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);

        # Display FPS on frame
        cv2.putText(frame_gray, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);

        # Display result
        cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame_gray)

        # Exit if ESC pressed
        if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same kind of things, so I hope maybe some of the things I encountered can help you (otherwise I'm sorry for giving a shit answer). I think you should not put it in gray, as it's asking for 3 channels (RGB instead of gray/BW). When you keep the "convert2gray" out, still you're putting: "thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]", which will give you also only 1 channel. Delete the "[1]" at the end and the conversion to gray and maybe it will then work?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I was not asking a question/looking for an answer, I was sharing some input to things I think will help make the script in the question work. Of course maybe the two possibilities I mentioned will not work, but for me this worked when I got the same error.